# Devise Username not saving in database ROR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, postgresql-9.4

First off, my question is very similar to other Devise username questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20136052/rails-4-devise-3-0-authenticate-using-username-and-email), but it is unique in that my problem appears to be the database.  I fully expect that once my question is answered it will result in a 'duh' moment for me, but I need a second pair of eyes.

My problem is that the sign up process works, and users are saved to the database and automatically logged in, except for the username saving.  Everything works except for that.  When first working toward a solution I figured that it was a problem with strong parameters, but username is included.... so here's the code:

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false}
  validate :validate_username

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  attr_accessor :login

  def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
    conditions = warden_conditions.dup
    if login = conditions.delete(:username)
      where(conditions).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
    else
      where(conditions).first
    end
  end

  def validate_username
    if User.where(email: username).exists?
      errors.add(:username, :invalid)
    end
  end
end
```

application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
end
```

devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email, :username]
  config.authentication_keys = [:login]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email, :username]
  config.confirmation_keys = [:login]
  config.reset_password_keys = [:login]

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers:  {
    registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }
...
end
```

I have also edited the views to have username fields

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true %>
  </div>
```

Is there something I'm missing that would allow all the other information to save to the database properly but prevent username from saving?

Thank you for any and all help

EDIT: Here's the schema for 'users' to show that I do indeed have username.

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "username",               default: "", null: false
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
end

add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
```

And my server log for the most recent test:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-04 13:21:07 -0700
Processing by Users::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"r+jgrIFotF3juYTmMiZhH3K23jzsnTfJOJ6K3kafjfyESs9uX95QKfCSUZQwjS6nyxnOVLpMH4g3S2FNfIGAbA==", "user"=>{"username"=>"test9", "email"=>"test9@test9.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
 (6.7ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('test9') LIMIT 1
  User Exists (5.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["email", "test9"]]
  User Exists (0.9ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test9@test9.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "test9@test9.com"], ["encrypted_password", "deleted"], ["created_at", "2015-10-04 20:21:08.017736"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-04 20:21:08.017736"]]
   (8.0ms)  COMMIT
   (14.0ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "last_sign_in_ip" = $3, "current_sign_in_ip" = $4, "sign_in_count" = $5, "updated_at" = $6 WHERE "users"."id" = $7  [["last_sign_in_at", "2015-10-04 20:21:08.060016"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2015-10-04 20:21:08.060016"], ["last_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1/32"], ["current_sign_in_ip", "127.0.0.1/32"], ["sign_in_count", 1], ["updated_at", "2015-10-04 20:21:08.083347"], ["id", 9]]
   (8.1ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 508ms (ActiveRecord: 47.1ms)
```

More information:

When running the User.create method in the console directly the username saves properly

```
[1] pry(main)> User.create(username: "test11", email: "test11@test11.com", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password")
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.0ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."username") = LOWER('test11') LIMIT 1
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["email", "test11"]]
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test11@test11.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("username", "email", "encrypted_password", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["username", "test11"], ["email", "test11@test11.com"], ["encrypted_password", "deleted"], ["created_at", "2015-10-05 17:22:11.677278"], ["updated_at", "2015-10-05 17:22:11.677278"]]
   (3.7ms)  COMMIT
=> #<User:0x00000004ac4550
 id: 10,
 username: "test11",
 email: "test11@test11.com",
 encrypted_password: "deleted",
```

and my users controller for registrations because I have tried params in both that controller as well as the application controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
before_filter :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
    binding.pry
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation) }
  end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a ton more trial and error and a couple suggestions from fellow coders I found that the problem was 2 part.  1 part was that I was not restarting my server often enough so some of the changes that I though I was testing were not actually loading.  The second part of my problem was that even though I had the strong params set in the application controller correctly, since I also had them set in my registrations_controller.rb as well (and not fully commented out) , the registrations_controller was overriding my other settings.  I did not have :login as a parameter in the registrations controller and (even though it is listed above) the listed change above did not register due to not restarting the server (See part 1)....   /facepalm